# Why does XAML Margin not follow CSS norm?

Tags: wpf, xaml, margin

In CSS the margin order is: **top right bottom left**

In XAML the margin order is: **left top right bottom**

Is there a reason why the WPF team didn't align this to the CSS norm?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I imagine this is because margins in WinForms were declared as left, top, right, bottom.  They likely thought it would be more likely to have WinForms developers move on to WPF rather than those from the web.

For reference you can check the [constructor for the Padding structure on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x17zs1da.aspx) (the type used for the Margin property).

Comment: Correct ! :) in Winforms the serialization of a Margin value as a string is done left top right bottom, you beat me to it.

Answer (score 18):

They're not aligning to CSS norms - they're aligning with the way that Microsoft has done UI APIs in the past.  I can't speak for WinForms, but in MFC coordinates are specified in the order of LTRB.

Comment: And its ancestor, the RECT structure in Windows API before that!