# Properties order in Margin

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

If I have such string in XAML:

```
Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" From="1,2,3,4" To="0,0,0,0"
```

What is Top Bottom Right and Left?
1- right
2- top
3- left
4 - bottom

Is that right?

Comment: Second result when searching for WPF margin order, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520422/why-does-xaml-margin-not-follow-css-norm. left top right bottom

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.margin

Comment: @PapaJohn To be more specific to the link `@amit jha` provided, look at the section titled `XAML Values` for the margin in that link.

Answer (score 488, accepted):

```
Margin="1,2,3,4"
```

1. Left,
2. Top,
3. Right,
4. Bottom

It is also possible to specify just two sizes like this:

```
Margin="1,2"
```

1. Left AND right
2. Top AND bottom

Finally you can specify a single size:

```
Margin="1"
```

1. used for all sides

The order is the same as in WinForms.

Comment: LTRB is the short notation to remember easily.

Comment: Note: this is a different order than html's css order, which is Top, Right, Bottom, Left.

Comment: Anyone have any insight into why they decided to go with something different from CSS?

Comment: @crclayton - As I wrote; the order is the same as in WinForms. WinForms is the natural predecessor for WPF so software (developers) would upgrade from WinForms to WPF.

Comment: How about. WPF starts in the West. Netscape starts in the North? And obviously clockwise for both.

Comment: @CharlesClayton - presumably WinForms inherited this sequence from MFC CRect which inherits Windows API structure RECT.

Answer (score 47):

There are three unique situations:

- **4 numbers**, e.g. `Margin="a,b,c,d"`.
- **2 numbers**, e.g. `Margin="a,b"`.
- **1 number**, e.g. `Margin="a"`.

### 4 Numbers

If there are **4 numbers**, then its `left`, `top`, `right`, `bottom` (a clockwise circle starting from the middle left margin). First number is always the "West" like "WPF":

```
<object Margin="left,top,right,bottom"/>
```

Example: if we use `Margin="10,20,30,40"` it generates:

[image]

### 2 Numbers

If there are **2 numbers**, then the first is left & right margin thickness, the second is top & bottom margin thickness. First number is always the "West" like "WPF":

```
<object Margin="a,b"/> // Equivalent to Margin="a,b,a,b".
```

Example: if we use `Margin="10,30"`, the left & right margin are both 10, and the top & bottom are both 30.

[image]

### 1 Number

If there is **1 number**, then the number is repeated (its essentially a border thickness).

```
<object Margin="a"/> // Equivalent to Margin="a,a,a,a".
```

Example: if we use `Margin="20"` it generates:

[image]

## Update 2020-05-27

Have been working on a large-scale WPF application for the past 5 years with over 100 screens. Part of a team of 5 WPF/C#/Java devs. We eventually settled on either using 1 number (for border thickness) or 4 numbers. We never use 2. It is consistent, and seems to be a good way to reduce cognitive load when developing.

---

The rule:

> All width numbers start on the left (the "West" like "WPF") and go clockwise (if two numbers, only go clockwise twice, then mirror the rest).

Comment: "If there are 2 numbers, then the first is left & right margin thickness" But in the example the first number is 30, and it ends up being the top & bottom margin.

Answer (score 23):

Just because @MartinCapodici 's comment is awesome I write here as an answer to give visibility.

All clockwise:

- **W**PF start ***W***est (left->top->right->bottom)
- **N**etscape (ie CSS) start ***N***orth (top->right->bottom->left)

Answer (score 7):

```
<object Margin="left,top,right,bottom"/>
- or - 
<object Margin="left,top"/>
- or - 
<object Margin="thicknessReference"/>
```

See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.margin.aspx

Comment: For the second example, "left,top", its actually repeated: the first number refers to left & right, the second to top & bottom, see my answer below.